# Sudden degrading of windows performance

Tags: windows-10, performance, malware

My windows 10 system has had a significance drop in general UI performance in the last day.

There is noticeable lag of nearly 0.5 seconds when you resize a window, for example.  It happens in most applications.

I tried installing the latest video card (NVIDIA) drivers but that didn't help.

Could this be caused by malware?  Or something else?

EDIT:
System specs: i7-8750 (hex core), 16GB Ram, 124GB free space on SSD, plugged in with 100% battery.
Task manager shows 10% CPU usage, mostly from Chrome & Firefox.
BUT... task manager takes about 3-4 seconds to load

EDIT2: 
Occasionally "System interrupts" takes up 50% of the CPU, as shown by task manager..

EDIT3: I ran malwarebytes and it did not find anything.

Comment: Said like that, it's hard to tell. How much RAM and CPU cycles is in use when that happens? How much RAM do you have in total, how much free space on your HDD or SSD, is your system fully up-to-date, what's the size of your pagefile(s), etc...? Tell us more about your hardware and software setup.

Comment: @Didier I updated it.  It's a medium-high end gaming laptop, and the issue persists even if I restart windows and have no programs open.

Comment: Have you checked for viruses, eg bitcoin miner?

Comment: @DavidPostill No.  That's what I'm asking basically, how can I check for this?  Is that a likely cause?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit?s=3|0.0000

Comment: In addition to the above, get the Hardware Test application from the Computer Vendor and test hardware - especially the drive.  It may have errors causing this.

Comment: High interrupts usually denotes a hardware issue, either a struggling WiFi or Ethernet card, or a loose USB connection to an external peripheral, something like that. As John mentioned, a problem with your SSD (bad seat?) could also cause such high interrupts, but 50% is a rare occurrence indeed.

Comment: @Didier Can I possibly fix it with a chipset update?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "chipset update". If you're thinking BIOS, and there's one available for your PC on the vendor's website, or on the website of the motherboard's vendor, then yes, you can flash a more recent BIOS, *using caution*. For the rest, have you tried to disconnect any USB device that was attached to your PC to see if there's improvement on the Interrupts front? If you go into Device Management, do you see any line bearing an icon indicating that the device is offline, or needs attention? If you temporarily disable all your network connections, do your Interrupts drop?

Comment: @Didier No I mean like Intel releases windows drivers for the motherboard chipset; is it worth updating this

Comment: It is, when it's available, but they're few and far between. You can unfold the whole System peripherals section in Device Manager and check for driver updates, one by one. Sometimes, you get a new one.